# Class Level Instance Variables in Ruby

Tags: ruby, class, instance-variables, class-variables

Please help me to understand Class Level Instance Variables.

@@ is a class variable and is an equivalent to instance variable (@) in a class instance.

But what is an instance variable (@) when used on class level? If it puts a definition to class instance then why not to define it in an initializer?

```
class MyClass
  cattr_reader :class_variable

  def self.new_instance(cv, cliv, iv)
    @@class_variable = cv
    @class_level_instance_variable = cliv
    self.new(iv)
  end

  def initialize(iv)
    @instance_variable = iv
  end

  def use
    puts "class_var=#{self.class.class_variable.inspect}\ninst_var=#{@instance_variable.inspect}\ncliv=#{@class_level_instance_variable.inspect}"
  end
end

c = []
c << MyClass.new_instance(1,2,3)
c[0].use
c << MyClass.new_instance(4,5,6)
c[1].use
c << MyClass.new_instance(7,8,9)
c[2].use

c[0].use
c[1].use
c[2].use
```

Comment: When you set instance variable on class level, it becomes class instance variable, which is something slightly different (and not really equivalent) to class variable. More info here:
http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2006/11/18/class-and-instance-variables-in-ruby/

Comment: @Marek Lipka: so, if I understood right, class level instance variables are fully equivalent to pre-initialized instance level instance variables and if I make multiple class instances in a class method each of these instances becomes initialized with this variable.

Comment: No, there is no such behavior at all. I only mean class level instance variable is *regular* instance variable, but bound to the class object (remember in Ruby classes are also objects).

Comment: @Paul: Why don't you throw in some code to illustrate what you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your answer you don't output the class level instance variable. Besides the usual syntax (`@foo`), an instance variable can be accessed via a method (`instance_variable_get(:@foo)`). You can use this method to read instance variables of other objects, not only `self`.

Here's a modified version of your code

```
require 'active_support/core_ext'

class MyClass
  cattr_reader :class_variable

  def self.new_instance(cv, cliv, iv)
    @@class_variable = cv
    @class_level_instance_variable = cliv
    self.new(iv)
  end

  def initialize(iv)
    @instance_variable = iv
  end

  def use
    puts "class_var=#{self.class.class_variable.inspect}"
    puts "class inst var: #{self.class.instance_variable_get(:@class_level_instance_variable)}"
    puts "inst_var=#{@instance_variable.inspect}"
  end
end

c = []
c << MyClass.new_instance(1,2,3)
c << MyClass.new_instance(4,5,6)
c << MyClass.new_instance(7,8,9)

c[0].use
c[1].use
c[2].use
# >> class_var=7
# >> class inst var: 8
# >> inst_var=3
# >> class_var=7
# >> class inst var: 8
# >> inst_var=6
# >> class_var=7
# >> class inst var: 8
# >> inst_var=9
```

See, class inst var is always 8 (just as class var is always 7). This is because you output values after all your modifications are made. And since class level variables are shared, the last modification wins.

```
c << MyClass.new_instance(7,8,9)
```

If you were to output from initializer (as was in your first version of code), you'd see different results.

```
# >> class_var=1
# >> class inst var: 2
# >> inst_var=3
# >> class_var=4
# >> class inst var: 5
# >> inst_var=6
# >> class_var=7
# >> class inst var: 8
# >> inst_var=9
```

Comment: So, a class level instance variable gives a way to communicate between children because is passed by reference to each instance. Right?

Comment: Yep, it's shared between all instances of the class.

Answer (score 3):

Hopefully this example will explain the difference between @ (instance) and @@ (class) variables.

```
class Animal
  @@total_count = 0

  def self.total_count
    @@total_count
  end

  def initialize
    @@total_count += 1
  end
end

class Cat < Animal
end

Animal.new
Animal.new
Cat.new

Animal.total_count # => 3
Cat.total_count # => 3
```

As you can see the @@ variable is shared between class and its children. If I really want to count the number of instances of the classes I have to use the following code.

```
class Animal
  class << self
    attr_accessor :total_count
  end

  @total_count = 0

  def self.total_count
    @total_count
  end

  def initialize
    self.class.total_count += 1
  end
end

class Cat < Animal
  @total_count = 0
end

Animal.new
Animal.new
Cat.new

Animal.total_count # => 2
Cat.total_count # => 1
```